# Does case automatically breaks?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

consider this case :

```
case when 4 > 3 then dbms_output.put_line('3');
     when 4 > 2 then dbms_output.put_line('2');
     when 4 > 1 then dbms_output.put_line('1');
end case;
```

What will the output be? Will it echo all three statements? If it will, how do I break a switch case in pl/sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm).

Once a condition is found to be true, the case statement will return the result and not evaluate the conditions any further. Further explanation can be found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php).

The syntax for the case statement is:

> CASE [ expression ]
>
> WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
>
> WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
>
> ...
>
> WHEN condition_n THEN result_n
>
> ELSE result
>
> END

expression is optional. It is the value that you are comparing to the list of conditions. (ie: condition_1, condition_2, ... condition_n)

condition_1 to condition_n must all be the same datatype. Conditions are evaluated in the order listed. Once a condition is found to be true, the case statement will return the result and not evaluate the conditions any further.

result_1 to result_n must all be the same datatype. This is the value returned once a condition is found to be true.

Comment: I missed that line when I read the documentation :) thanks.